# Send parameter from my onclick to a function as a value

Tags: javascript

I am really struggling with a very simple task but don't know what is my problem.

This is a part of my html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(hello.world)">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(world.hello)">Link 2</a>
```

And my JS code is:

```
function myFunction(id1) {
var text = id1;
alert(text);
}
```

So I need to alert "hello.world" or any other parameter.

Please amend my jsfiddle to make it working so I know where is my problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/9xhxzh89/5/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them with quotes:

```js
function myFunction(id1) {
    var text = id1;
    alert(text);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('hello.world')">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('world.hello')">Link 2</a>
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xhxzh89/6/)